# Relationship between the length of the tangent line through a point on sphere and great-circle distance

Tags: spherical-trigonometry

As an aviator I'm familiar with the concept of great-circle navigation because when we fly a route between 2 points on the globe we know the shortest distance between these two points is the great circle distance.

I'm developing a navigation app in Google Earth and I need to calculate the shortest distance from the surface of the "spherical" Earth to any point on the tangent line through A (origin) when flying the great circle path.

Also, I'm using a mean earth radius of 6,371.009 km for WGS84 ellipsoid.

Just to be clear, I'd like to refer to the diagram in the following link:

http://www.alaricstephen.com/main-featured/2017/5/22/the-haversine-formula

I use the Haversine formula to calculate the distance, d, between the points A and D (see diagram). **What I'd like to calculate is the distance D to E as a function of d.**

In the diagram this is referred to as the external secant (exsec) which is the portion DE of the secant exterior to the circle.

Comment: Do you have a figure?

Comment: I rephrased my question referring to a diagram I found in the following link http://www.alaricstephen.com/main-featured/2017/5/22/the-haversine-formula

Comment: The tangent line from a point is not unique. If you mean the tangent line in the plane of the great circle, then your problem is a planar one and you don't need any spherical trigonometry. Now it is unclear if you use a spherical or ellipsoidal model.

Comment: That diagram uses a unit circle, and it says that the distance ED is $\sec\theta-1$.

Comment: If you *would* like to use an ellipsoidal model, take a look at Charles Karney's free [geographiclib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/). FWIW, Dr Karney is a major contributor to the Wikipedia articles on ellipsoidal navigation. geographiclib is written in C++, but with bindings available in many languages. Karney's algorithms always converge (unlike the old Vincenty algos), and whereas Vincenty can often give errors of a metre or more, the error from Karney's algorithms are on the order of a nanometre, when used on the WGS84 ellipsoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$r=OE\cos\theta$$

and

$$DE=r\sec\frac{\stackrel\frown{AD}}r-r.$$

Comment: Yes, I do mean the tangent line in the plane of the great circle. To calculate DE, I assume a circle with mean radius r which will have some error knowing that Google Earth is WGS84 ellipsoid.

Comment: @rgraulus: then my formula holds.

Answer (score 1):

[HaverSine Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) is used routinely to compute long distances in navigation along shortest path great circles of the Earth between two points of given latitude and longitude.

[image]

First find $d$ on the Earth. Next air distance along a tangent if the flight point $B$ is above the Earth: $ t= r \tan \dfrac{d}{r}.$

$-------------------------$

After clarification the above can be ignored.

For perfect sphere model of earth it is simple trig. calculation.

Distance $ AD= r \theta =  $ the arc distance you calculated using Haversine formula along a great circle arc of earth radius $=r$ as shown. Calculate $ \theta $ in radians in the plane of kite shape $OAEB$ if we imagine $B$ on another tangent point below. We have $  \theta= \dfrac{\text{arc} AD}{r}$

[image]

Central dimension is length $OE$. From this subtract earth radius.

$$ DE = r \sec \theta - r\; = r (\sec \theta -1 )$$

This is the red height above target/destination/landing place which should vanish on landing at $D$. It is indicated by ***exsec*** in the supplied link   for unit earth radius.

Comment: I edited my question referring to a diagram I found in the following link http://www.alaricstephen.com/main-featured/2017/5/22/the-haversine-formula

Comment: So I updated my answer.